# I am using FLEX property in my code but it is not working for ios 7/8 devices. How to make it work for ios7/8?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am using FLEX in my code but the output is not as expected for ios 7/8 devices.

```
<div className="modal-row">
    <div className="col1">
        <span>{dict.YourServiceNumber}</span>
    </div>
    <div className="col2">
        <span>{this.props.mobileNumber}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**MyCssFile.css:**

```
.modal-row {
    display: flex;
}

.col1 {
    flex: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}

.col2 {
    flex: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

It is working fine for ios versions above 9 and desktop browsers.
Please help me to make the code work for IOS 7/8 devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) Flexbox is supported for iOS Safari 7 and 8 but you need to prefix it with the `-webkit-` prefix.

Change you CSS to this:

```
.modal-row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.col1 {
    -webkit-flex: 50%;
    text-align: left;
}

.col2 {
    -webkit-flex: 50%;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
}
```